# How to launch a URL in IE10 from within a Windows 8 WInJS application?

Tags: winjs

this might be a silly question but I have not been able to find an answer. I want to launch a specific URL with IE10 from within my Windows 8 javascript application, i.e. my application will be suspended and IE10 will launch. How do I do that with javascript?

Thanks
Themos

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.google.com")
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(url);
```

Comment: No probs. Updated the example.

Comment: But its opening on edge browser , not on any specific IE , @MichaelBrearley