# How to launch a URL in IE instead of Edge from a Windows 8/10 WInJS application

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, win-universal-app, winjs

I want to open one URL on IE browser not on default edge browser from a windows 8.1/10 universal application using phonegap,WinJS etc..

I got same question
[How to launch a URL in IE10 from within a Windows 8 WInJS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600359/how-to-launch-a-url-in-ie10-from-within-a-windows-8-winjs-application)  but the solution from this question is not working as its opening on default edge browser.

I am using cordova ,WinJs to develop this application.

i have tried inAppBrowser and its also opening on default edge even if we specify metatag specifically to any of the IE version like this.

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

and also tried from C# using runtime component but every time its opening on EDGE browser but i need specific IE (IE9 or IE10 etc... )

Answer (score 1):

> Windows Store apps cannot launch specific apps. The can launch documents or URIs only into the default handler for the type

From MSDN thread:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1c93b5a8-ead8-4e51-83f3-763b1db53324/how-to-open-nondefault-browser-on-clicking-hyperlink-having-target-blank-in-webview-?forum=winappswithcsharp